# Finding which ul list's a link has been clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I can get the current link being clicked using the following code, which returns a number, telling me the n-th link has been clicked:

```
    $("#thumbs ul a").live('click',function(){
        index_image = $("#thumbs ul a").index(this);
    }
```

However, I want to know which ul list has the clicked link inside of it. I also want this to return a number e.g. the 2nd ul has been clicked. I have been trying the following solutions with little luck:

```
    //Solution One
    $("#thumbs ul a").live('click',function(){
        index_image = $("#thumbs ul a").index(this);
        $("#thumbs ul a").parent('ul').index(this);
    }

    //Solution Two
    $("#thumbs ul").live('click',function(){
        $("#thumbs ul").index(this);
    }
```

The HTML is marked up as follows:

```
    <div id="thumbs">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
       </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
       </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you expect the returned number to go to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try solution one with this:

```
//Solution One
$("#thumbs ul a").live('click',function(){
    index_image = $("#thumbs ul a").index(this);
    var parentUl = $(this).closest('ul'); // this will return the ul container object
}
```

You can then do whatever with the parentUl variable, which is a reference to the ul element you are looking for.

Comment: This didn't provide the solution, but it did help me massively to find the solution. Which is as follows:
    $("#thumbs ul a").live('click',function(){
        index_image = $("#thumbs ul a").index(this);
        var parentUl = $(this).closest('ul'); // this will return the ul container object
         index_line = $("#thumbs ul").index(parentUl);
    }

Comment: Glad it helped. I wasn't sure what you wanted with the parentUl object so I just left it there for you to play around with.